# How to open ngx-daterangepicker-material outside button/icon if multiple date range picker is available in same form

Tags: angular, ngx-daterangepicker-material

I want to open my ngx-daterangepicker-material by clicking out side of any button/icon. i know ngx-daterangepicker-material provide the facility by using

```
@ViewChild(DaterangepickerDirective, { static: false }) pickerDirective: DaterangepickerDirective.
....
openDatepicker() {
   
    this.pickerDirective.open();
  }
```

But my problem is not resolved with above code as I have a multiple date range picker in my form. When i tried with the above code .it will open the date range picker but the value is set only on first date range picker. not on particular date range which I clicked.

Any help will be appreciate

[image]

Comment: add template variable (like #myfirstdaterangepicker) at your datepicker tag in html. and use it multiple viewChild @ViewChild('myfirstdaterangepicker', {.. then call open method on whatever datepicker you want to open.

Comment: Thanks @HPSingh for reply but my form is dynamic i have only on date range picker in html and in runtime I called my template in for each loop if i add this #myfirstdaterangepicker it will be render multiple time with same template id

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can try to send the #daterangepickerreference to openDatepicker(daterangepickerreference: DaterangepickerDirective) method, when you are clicking and calling openDatepicker method.

Comment: I prepared the same, and looks like it would work https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hvcnpx

Comment: Thanks again but above exmple is simple in my case you cannot apply and open the date range picker in same event like                                       
 openDatepicker(inputRef) {
   
    this.pickerDirective.open();
    inputRef.value = this.pickerDirective.value;
  }           <input formControlName="{{'plannedStartDate'+ activity.rowId}}" #datePiker
                               />
                             <mat-icon  class="ngx-daterangepicker-action"   (click)="openDatepicker(datePiker)">date_range</mat-icon>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ViewChild you can use ViewChildren
Something like
@ViewChildren(DaterangepickerDirective) pickerDirectiveAll: Query
Then in your (click)="openDatepicker(datePiker) you need to loop through pickerDirectiveAll and finds your specific item.

- find item (in think its working if u compare by this.pickerDirectiveAll[i].viewContainerRef == datePiker)
  then open: this.pickerDirectiveAll[i].open();

But it's not so elegant solution...